# Csv Data is not loading properly as Parquet using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, parquet, hdf

I have a table in **Hive**

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab_data (
  rec_id INT,
  rec_name STRING,
  rec_value DECIMAL(3,1),
  rec_created TIMESTAMP
) STORED AS PARQUET;
```

and I want to populate this table with data in **.csv** files like these

```
10|customer1|10.0|2016-09-07  08:38:00.0
20|customer2|24.0|2016-09-08  10:45:00.0
30|customer3|35.0|2016-09-10  03:26:00.0
40|customer1|46.0|2016-09-11  08:38:00.0
50|customer2|55.0|2016-09-12  10:45:00.0
60|customer3|62.0|2016-09-13  03:26:00.0
70|customer1|72.0|2016-09-14  08:38:00.0
80|customer2|23.0|2016-09-15  10:45:00.0
90|customer3|30.0|2016-09-16  03:26:00.0
```

using **Spark** and **Scala** with code as below

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataTypes, IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType}

object MainApp {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("MainApp")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","200") 
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val inputPath = "hdfs://host.hdfs:8020/..../tab_data.csv"
  val outputPath = "hdfs://host.hdfs:8020/...../warehouse/test.db/tab_data"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    try {

      val DecimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(3, 1)

      /**
        * schema
        */
      val schema = StructType(List(StructField("rec_id", IntegerType, true), StructField("rec_name",StringType, true),
        StructField("rec_value",DecimalType),StructField("rec_created",TimestampType, true)))

      /**
        * Reading the data from HDFS 
        */
      val data = spark
        .read
        .option("sep","|")
        .schema(schema)
        .csv(inputPath)

      data.show(truncate = false)
      data.schema.printTreeString()

      /**
        * Writing the data as Parquet
        */
      data
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .parquet(outputPath)

    } finally {
      sc.stop()    
      spark.stop()
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting this output

```scala
+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|rec_id|rec_name|rec_value|rec_created|
+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |
|null  |null    |null     |null       |


root
 |-- rec_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rec_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rec_value: decimal(3,1) (nullable = true)
 |-- rec_created: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

The schema is fine but the data is not loading properly in the table

```sql
SELECT * FROM tab_data;

+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+--+
| tab_data.rec_id  | tab_data.rec_name  | tab_data.rec_value  | tab_data.rec_created  |
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+--+
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
| NULL             | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                  |
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new with **Spark** and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could have directly use insertInto instead of writing data to hdfs location..as your table is managed table

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, thanks for your support. Yeah! you are right, it can be done in that way, but for me, technical and business rules are imposed from others :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `null` values in all columns because one of the column of type `String` is not able convert to `Timestamp` type.

To convert string to timestamp type, specify timestamp format by using this `option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")` option while loading csv data.

Check below code.

**Schema**

```
scala> val schema = StructType(List(
   StructField("rec_id", IntegerType, true), 
   StructField("rec_name",StringType, true),
   StructField("rec_value",DecimalType(3,1)),
   StructField("rec_created",TimestampType, true))
)
```

**Loading CSV Data**

```
scala> val df = spark
.read
.option("sep","|")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
.schema(schema)
.csv("/tmp/sample")

scala> df.show(false)
+------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|rec_id|rec_name |rec_value|rec_created        |
+------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|10    |customer1|10.0     |2016-09-07 08:38:00|
|20    |customer2|24.0     |2016-09-08 10:45:00|
|30    |customer3|35.0     |2016-09-10 03:26:00|
|40    |customer1|46.0     |2016-09-11 08:38:00|
|50    |customer2|55.0     |2016-09-12 10:45:00|
|60    |customer3|62.0     |2016-09-13 03:26:00|
|70    |customer1|72.0     |2016-09-14 08:38:00|
|80    |customer2|23.0     |2016-09-15 10:45:00|
|90    |customer3|30.0     |2016-09-16 03:26:00|
+------+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

**Updated**

Since table is managed table, You don't need to set all those parameters, You can use `insertInto` function to insert the data into table.

```
df.write.mode("append").insertInto("tab_data")
```

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, I apply your changes and the dataframe output looks good, but I can't do ````SELECT * FROM tab_data;```` I am getting errors ````Error: java.io.IOException: parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file ......````.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another question would be: Why would I want to do ````.option("inferSchema","true")````. I don't want to infer the schema from the data, I believe it is a bit inefficient and I made up my own schema. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can remove this - option("inferSchema","true")..it's not mandatory..

Comment: Can you show create table statement for tab_data. And make sure before inserting this new data .. drop all the rows or file for that table..

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, the ````create table```` statement for tab_data is on top of the post.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with issues between `Spark`, `Hive` and `Parquet` set up your `SparkSession` as follow:

```scala
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("CsvToParquet")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","200") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", true) // To skip issues with data type between Spark and Hive
                                                         // The convention used by Spark to write Parquet data is configurable.
                                                         // This is determined by the property spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat
                                                         // The default value is false. If set to "true",
                                                         // Spark will use the same convention as Hive for writing the Parquet data.
```

afterwards read the `.csv` data as follow

```scala
      val data = spark
        .read
        .option("sep","|")
        .option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S") // to read timestamp fields
        .option("inferSchema",false) // by default is false
        .schema(schema)
        .csv(inputPath)
```

then write the data as `parquet` with `no compression`(by default data is compressed) as follow

```scala
      data
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .option("compression", "none") // Assuming no data compression
        .parquet(outputPath)
```

**Note:** It's probably that the reason why `Hive` cannot query the data is because data is compressed in `snappy` format by default and your `CREATE TABLE` statement stores the data as `parquet` without compression.

Comment: Hi @Chema, the code works fine, I can query the table. Thanks.