# NULLs when loading data with a schema in Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I would like to load data with Pyspark (from AWS s3) using a custom schema for the data types (as I did below). If I do this though I get `NULL` for all rows and columns. If I comment out `.schema(customSchema)` then everything works fine and I don't get only `NULL`s. Why do I get only `NULL`s?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType


customSchema = StructType([
    StructField("Date", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("xx", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("yy", StringType(), True),
    StructField("zz", StringType(), True)])


 
    
    
df = (glueContext
          .read
          .schema(customSchema)
          .load('s3://bucket/data.csv',
                           format="csv",
                           sep=",",
                           header=True)
         )

df.show()
```

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997718/csv-data-is-not-loading-properly-as-parquet-using-spark/62997865#62997865

Comment: can you show data sample?